# Inspect memory with gdb

Tags: debugging, memory, gdb, cpu-registers

I want to inspect address in GDB . There is address in r0 register that I want to inspect:

`(r0+10)->64`

How can I do that in 1 line using gdb?

Answer (score 2):

In gdb command line: `x/16xw 0x1000`
16: blocks
x: in hexadecimal
w: word(32bit)
0x1000: address of memory